# Помощь в реализации long-poll PHP

Tags: php, long-poll

Ребят, всем доброго времени суток. Нужна мне реализация long-polling механизма. Как это работает я уже понял. Но все еще не понятно как делать второй запрос не вызывая обработчик, а просто чекать результат первого вызова. Пример для наглядности. Допустим я вызвал событие создания пользователя, и жду пока адмен подтвердит мою заявку. Но адмен может проверять и 3 минуты, а держать открытое соединения я так долго не могу. Получается что нужно вызывать то же событие еще раз. Что создаст еще одного пользователя.

Можете объяснить что не так? Как вызывать только проверку, проверил админ или нет?

Comment: Ну так создай событие чекания статуса и юзай его

Comment: Вебсокеты вам нужны

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Очень даже нужны) Но в моем случае слишком сложно. Подымать сокет ради парочки функций как минимум нет смысла. Тем более socketIO Спокойно использует long-polling и нормально живут же люди.

Comment: Для забивания гвоздей я всегда использую молоток, а не обломок кирпича, даже если гвоздей всего пара штук

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Выходит что socketIO это кирпич, так им и напишу)

Comment: @makcim512 в древние времена вебсокет не везде поддерживался, поэтому сперва шел long-polling запрос с попыткой открыть вебсокет, если открывался -  long-polling умирал, в противном случае оставался висеть. А так-то да, сокетио тот ешё кирпич

Comment: long poll используется зачастую, если вы сами делаете какой-то длинный процесс,  и можете, подчеркиваю, МОЖЕТЕ себе позволить ждать N-е к-во времени. Если не можете, используйте обычный poll